# Unity - Detect new display connected at runtime in a build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an application that runs on two separate displays.
I'm using multidisplay and specifically `Display.displays.Length` to read the number monitors.
However, I've noticed that the number does not update if I connect a secondo monitor at runtime (in a build)

Any ideas on how to refresh that value so that I can target a camera to the second monitor only if this is connected?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation. In [Display.displays](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Display-displays.html) it states in editor this value is always 1 regardless monitor count. In built application it automatically updates when a device connected or lost connection.

Comment: Yea I’ve seen that thanks. But I’m talking about an actual build. I’ve edited the question to clarify that

Comment: In documentation it says it automatically updates but if its not happening on your build, try to report bug to the Unity. Or check display device value every 5 second with coroutine. It shouldn't slow your application.

Comment: I’m currently checking it and it’s always 1. I wonder if there’s something that can be done at a lower level to force refresh the update?